# How to connect postgres using python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, port

I tried connecting postgres using python by the followimg code. However I am not able to connect it I am getting some error.

```
import psycopg2
import sys

def main():
    #Define our connection string
    conn_string = "host='11.20.89.233' dbname='postgres' user='good_user' password='secret'"

    # print the connection string we will use to connect
    print "Connecting to database\n ->%s" % (conn_string)

    # get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this cursor to perform queries
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print "Connected!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I got the following error.

```
grtmgr@BLR1000005591:~/mppcases> python testcon.py
Connecting to database
        ->host='11.20.89.233' dbname='good_user' user='secret' 
password='mpp_tool'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcon.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "testcon.py", line 12, in main
     conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, 
in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "11.20.89.233" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 16100?
```

Comment: Are you sure that your postgres is listening on port `16100`? That is not standard.

Comment: Validate the IP, port and credentials are correct

Comment: Where to validate. IP and credentials are correct. Port I don't know where to validate.

Comment: Try connecting with them using standard client like psql or pgAdmin

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: default port is 5432 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you're using the correct port and second, you need to add you IP address to the PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf file.

`host    all             all             x.x.x.x/32            md5`